# Does SetThreadpoolCallbackPriority work for IO callbacks

Tags: c++, winapi, threadpool

The Win32 API has a function (actually a macro) named [`SetThreadpoolCallbackPriority()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405519.aspx).

I'd like to use it for thread pool I/O callbacks. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405519.aspx) is sparse, but mentions "work items". Google does not find many examples except [this blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/harip/2010/10/11/threadpool-work-item-priority/), which again talks about "work items".

Does priorization actually work for I/O? And if yes, how do I use it correctly?

Comment: What happens when you try to use it?

Comment: Nothing bad happens, I just can not see any effect in benchmarks, thus I'm asking. I do SetThreadpoolCallbackPriority() after creating IO to temporarily boost callback for some clients

Comment: define "IO callbacks"?

Comment: PTP_WIN32_IO_CALLBACK , as described in CreateThreadpoolIo documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Does priorization actually work for I/O

no, this have effect only for work items queued by call SubmitThreadpoolWork. how absolute correct noted in your link -

> This function does not modify thread priorities; instead it uses
>   separate queues for low, high and normal priority work items

so call SetThreadpoolCallbackPriority only indirect way pass TP_CALLBACK_PRIORITY Priority parameter to function SubmitThreadpoolWork(Work). for my look more logical will be do this direct and have next signature -

```
VOID WINAPI SubmitThreadpoolWork(
  __inout  PTP_WORK pwk, TP_CALLBACK_PRIORITY Priority
);
```

compare this with next function - [IoQueueWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549466(v=vs.85).aspx) - the SetThreadpoolCallbackPriority it user mode analog and parameter **WORK_QUEUE_TYPE QueueType** - like **TP_CALLBACK_PRIORITY Priority** - say to which queue (exist 3 different queues) insert work item. for I/O items this of course have no any effect. when working thread remove items - it first remove it from high priority, util it not empty, then from normal, and finally from low

Comment: Thanks! That would be pity if this does not work.  Do not know the internals of the threadpool implementation, but I could  imagine that if it dequeued OVERLAPPED in batches with GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx, it could do some priorization of the dequeued IO.  The only alternative I'm left with is to shuffle the dequeued item into prioritized work queue instead of processing it directly in the thread where it arrive, right?

Comment: no, when IO de queued it just called, for what you need prioritization of IO items ?

Comment: This is not easy to explain  shortly. Imagine, this is inside a database server, and I know that this client connection holds some important locks that other connections are waiting for, until the end of current transaction. So I want to boost this connection so it finishes faster, rather than letting other connections to wait on locks

Comment: understand, but how this related to dequeued order/prioritization ? you have several threads in pool (usual = number of processors), threads dequeue network operation finished (connect/recv/send) and process requests. not important in which order. if some request take more time and hold locks - how any prioritization here can help ?

Comment: The client hold locks, over multiple requests, until the COMMIT/ROLLBACK arrives. So if I prioritize this client's requests over others, chances are other clients would not have to wait on the locks. This just prevents the lock contention, improves concurrency, and reduces the number of threads in the pool

Comment: 'over multiple requests' - but IO items will be dequeued just IO operation finished. no option not remove this items, but wait until several another items dequeued (and some of it even not finished). so, if while process some client request, you acquire lock, another client requests will be wait on this lock. in any case wait

Comment: I expect transaction to be short, and I expect thousands of clients to queue requests fast.If I hold other clients (that is, give them lesser priority), and let this one run (that is, giving higher priority to him), lock contention is avoided. If we abstract from threadpool, and let's say do plain IOCP, GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx could retrieve 1000 completions, and one of those is the more important one, holding the locks, So I'd let him run sooner than others

Comment: ok, imaging some recv finished, and you begin transaction with locks. at this time you got finished packets for connect/recv on another sockets. you want that working threads not dequeued this packets or not call you callback with it ? how ?

Comment: If priorization worked, I would give this important item higher priority. I do not mind if a small number of worker threads runs in parallel. But I would mind if 1000 other less important requests are scheduled before the important one.

Comment: what you mean under "I would give this important item higher priority" ? and how i understand you will be need process several this kind of IO item in transaction. however i still not understand what logic you want implement here (i know that you mean MariaDB server)

Comment: Please take a look at https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/29/percona-server-thread-pool-improvements/ . This is implemented on Unix,with its own pooling logic. It allows dequeuing many items, and priorization is done in code (there are actual high and low priority queues that requests are put on after io arrives). https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/performance/threadpool.html under "Priority connection scheduling" also talks about that

Comment: you have pool of listening sockets. they wait for connect (with AcceptEx ?). after client connect you call WSARecv and wait for instructions. IO will be complete every time when new client connect or send some data (also when send/disconnect finished). so this items will be dequeued just IO operation finished. and before you got IO packet in callback you at all cannot know for which socket(client) it belong. all sockets binded to single IOCP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116573/discussion-between-vladislav-vaintroub-and-rbmm).